# Summarize non-zero values or any values from pandas dataframe with timestamps- From_Time & To_Time

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe given below
[image]
I want to extract all the non-zero values from each column to put it in a summarize way like this
[image]
If any value repeated for period of time then starting time of value should go in 'FROM' column and end time of value should go in 'TO' column with column name in 'BLK-ASB-INV' column and value should go in 'Scount' column. For this I have started to write the code like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("StringFault_Bagewadi_16-01-2020.xlsx")
df = df.set_index(['Date (+05:30)'])

cols=['BLK-ASB-INV', 'Scount', 'FROM', 'TO']
res=pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
for col in df.columns:
    ss=df[col].iloc[df[col].to_numpy().nonzero()[0]]
    .......
```

After that I am unable to think how should I approach to get the desired output. Is there any way to do this in python? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved my problem, I have written the code given below works perfectly for me.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("StringFault.xlsx")
df = df.set_index(['Date (+05:30)'])
cols=['BLK-ASB-INV', 'Scount', 'FROM', 'TO']
res=pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
for col in df.columns:
    device = []
    for i in range(len(df[col])):
        if df[col][i] == 0:
            None
        else:    
            if i < len(df[col])-1 and df[col][i]==df[col][i+1]:
                try: 
                    if df[col].index[i] > device[2]:
                        continue
                except IndexError:
                    device.append(df[col].name)
                    device.append(df[col][i])
                    device.append(df[col].index[i])
                continue
            else:

                 if len(device)==3:
                     device.append(df[col].index[i])
                     res = res.append({'BLK-ASB-INV':device[0], 'Scount':device[1], 'FROM':device[2], 'TO': device[3]}, ignore_index=True) 
                     device=[]
                 else:
                     device.append(df[col].name)
                     device.append(df[col][i])
                     if i == 0:
                         device.append(df[col].index[i])
                     else:
                         device.append(df[col].index[i-1])
                     device.append(df[col].index[i])
                     res = res.append({'BLK-ASB-INV':device[0], 'Scount':device[1], 'FROM':device[2], 'TO': device[3]}, ignore_index=True) 
                     device=[]
```

For reference, here is the output datafarme
[image]